# Redireccionar pagina web según país

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola comunidad en esta ocación estoy creando una web multi nacional es decir que la pagina esta dividida en distintas versiones con las monedas locales de cada país, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando un cliente entre a: **ejemplo.com**

esta lo redirija a la de su país ya sea

**Colombia:** co.ejemplo.com
**Argentina** arg.ejemplo.com

Y así sucecivamente.

PD: ya busque en Google y no encuentro una solución.

para ser mas especifico si entramos a **godaddy.com** => esta nos redirige a el pais de origen es decír **ve.godaddy.com** (godaddy Venezuela)

Answer (score 6):

PHP no incluye en su API por defecto ninguna librería ni funciones para geolocalizar una IP, pero sí existen extensiones.

Te recomiendo que uses la extensión GeoIP: http://php.net/manual/es/book.geoip.php

Una vez la instales es muy sencillo obtener los datos de un país.

Por ejemplo si quieres obtener el nombre completo del país:

```
$nombre_pais = geoip_country_name_by_name($ip);
```

Si quieres obtener el código:

```
$codigo_pais = geoip_country_code_by_name($ip);
```

Una vez que tengas los datos del país, lo único que debes hacer es una redirección al sitio que quieras mostrar.

Comment: Existe una API más moderna, que es la sucesora de la que indicas en el enlace. Se llama [`GeoIP2`](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php). En Github se explica cómo instalarla y usarla.

Comment: Creo que debo instalar algún modulo para poder usarla en el servidor cierto ?

Comment: Sí, en este enlace están las instrucciones:  http://php.net/manual/es/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 2):

Yo utilizo la base de datos de http://www.ip2nation.com  y este scrip
y me funciona bastante bien. El scrip busca en la base de datos el codigo del pais en funcion de la IP del visitante y porteriormente hace la redicccion

```
$server   = ''; // MySQL hostname
$username = ''; // MySQL username
$password = ''; // MySQL password
$dbname   = ''; // MySQL db name


$db = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = 'SELECT 
            country
        FROM 
            ip2nation
        WHERE 
            ip < INET_ATON("'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'") 
        ORDER BY 
            ip DESC 
        LIMIT 0,1';

list($country) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql));

switch ($country) {
    case 'se':
        // Get the Swedish to a Swedish newssite
        header('Location: http://www.thelocal.se/');
        exit;
    case 'us':
        // And redirect US visitors to CNN
        header('Location: http://www.cnn.com/');
        exit;
    default:
        // The rest of the world can go to BBC
        header('Location: http://www.bbc.co.uk/');
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo mejor es ejemplo.com/pais puedes usar un geoplugin de php yo resolvi con esto: http://datoweb.com/post/2384-redirigir-trafico-segun-pais-visitante-con-php